# Obfuscate C code

Tags: c, obfuscation

I came across this obfuscated code recently:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _____(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)(i##r##s##o)
#define _ _____(m,i,n,u,a,l,s)

int _()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

What is happening here? How is it that `_()` is `main()`?

Edit:
I was looking for the 'technical term' that has been used here.

Comment: these macros just replace one thing with another - not hard to follow it through to see how

Comment: Look up "token pasting".

Comment: It is just a macro with arguments gluing some of the arguments to form a string and not using the others to confuse the reader.

Comment: This is not useful to future SO users/visitors.

Comment: @MartinJames [Wrong!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641847/how-does-this-c-program-compile-and-run-there-is-no-main-and-the-macros-are-ve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_` is replaced by `____(m,i,n,u,a,l,s)`

`____(m,i,n,u,a,l,s)` which is filtered through the macro `____(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)(i##r##s##o)`

`i##r##s##o` pastes the arguments `i, r, s, o` together to form text.  `i = m`, `r = a`, `s = i`, `o = n`, thus you get `main`

This technique is called 'token pasting'.  It is not something you'll use everyday, but there are times where it can be very useful.  See GCC's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) on token pasting.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. What is this technique called?